# Selecting a parent based on a nested childs data attributes

Tags: css

I'm successfully selecting a user avatar using this neat has selector:

```
  ul.remaining [data-avatar-for-person-id="44220253"] {
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
  }
```

Is it possible to use the has selector to select the parent li for this todo?

I'm trying like this, but its not being applied to the element - at all, not just because of specificality.

```
  li:has(img[data-avatar-for-person-id="44220253"] ) {
    font-size: 1.05em !important;
    color: black !important;
  }
```

the image is burried down in some divs and spans within the li.

I'm using firefox, but have enabled the experimental feature:

https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:has` selector works for me in Chrome. If this isn't working for you in Firefox, make sure you have the latest version, check that the feature is enabled, restart Firefox then check to make sure it's still enabled.

```css
p {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p:has([data-id="bar"]) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><span data-id="foo">Foo</span></p>
<p><span data-id="bar">Bar</span></p>
```

Comment: While this may work for a developer, the average user is not going to enable the experimental flag. That said, according to the MOZ Connect thread on `has()` should ship with FF 120. https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/when-is-has-css-selector-going-to-be-fully-implemented-in/idi-p/23794/page/5#comments

Comment: Hi Yes I worked out it was the flag and came back to add an answer.  but you are right so have a tick.  thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-has) i needed to enable the feature for firefox current version (118)

So I visted `about:config` and searched for has-selector and set

```
layout.css.has-selector.enabled true
```

And now my custom stylesheet works, enabling me to highlight todos assigned to me in basecamp 4. yay.